# numpy select fixed amount of values among duplicate values in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Starting from a simple array with duplicate values:

```
a = np.array([2,3,2,2,3,3,2,1])
```

I'm trying to select a maximum of 2 unique values from this. The resulting array would appear as:

```
b = np.array([2,3,2,3,1])
```

no matter the order of the items. So far I tried to find unique values with:

```
In [20]: c = np.unique(a,return_counts=True)

In [21]: c
Out[21]: (array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 4, 3]))
```

which is useful because it returns the frequency of values as well, but I'm stucked in filtering by frequency.

Comment: Do you want the resulting array to keep the initial order?

Comment: @Reti43 no matter the order thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension within `np.concatenate()` and limit the number of items by slicing:

```
>>> np.concatenate([a[a==i][:2] for i in np.unique(a)])
array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to generate the desired array from the array of `uniques` and `count`s:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,3,2,2,3,3,2,1])
uniques, count = np.unique(a,return_counts=True)
np.repeat(uniques, np.clip(count, 0, 2))
```

yields

```
array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

`np.clip` is used to force all values in `count` to be between 0 and 2. Thus, you get at most two values for each unique value.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach to keep the order as in the input array -

```
N = 2    # Number of duplicates to keep for each unique element

sortidx = a.argsort()
_,id_arr = np.unique(a[sortidx],return_index=True)

valid_ind = np.unique( (id_arr[:,None] + np.arange(N)).ravel().clip(max=a.size-1) )
out = a[np.sort(sortidx[valid_ind])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [253]: a
Out[253]: array([ 0, -3,  0,  2,  0,  3,  2,  0,  2,  3,  3,  2,  1,  5,  0,  2])

In [254]: N
Out[254]: 3

In [255]: out
Out[255]: array([ 0, -3,  0,  2,  0,  3,  2,  2,  3,  3,  1,  5])

In [256]: np.unique(out,return_counts=True)[1] # Verify the counts to be <= N
Out[256]: array([1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1])
```